# Import of .SQL file is very slow with HeidiSQL

Tags: debian, database, mariadb, galera

I have a database on a MariaDB server that I need to copy on a Galera Cluster on other machines. I used HeidiSQL to create a dump file which is pretty fast actually. The database is about 500Mb. However, when I tried to import it on the other server (still with HeidiSQL) it took around 8 hours to complete. I also tried to import it on a classic MariaDB server, same problem.

Is there a way to reduce that import time ?

Comment: What options were used on the dump?  One of them leads to the reload being 10 times as slow.  You can compensate somewhat for that.

Comment: Database : Create
Table : Create
Data : INSERT
INSERT size : 1024

Comment: More details, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to copy the database from the command line with mysqldump and copy it to the other server. It was way faster so I guess the problem comes from my internet speed at home.